# Using net5.0 in T4 templates in Rider

Tags: t4, .net-5, rider

I'm a little confused about compatibilities between `netstandard`, `netframework`, `netX` and how mono fits into the picture...

I understand that Rider's T4 engine runs on mono, but does that mean I can't use `net5.0` assemblies in my T4 templates?

Currently, I have a `net5.0` project, referencing `net5.0` nuget assemblies.

In my T4 templates, I'm referencing the assembly DLLs in `bin/Debug/net5.0` with `<@ assembly name="...">

When I run the T4 templates in-proc in a `net5.0` Console Application via  `Mono.TextTemplating.TemplateGenerator.TemplateGenerator`, then the templates work.

However, if I right-click a template in the Solution explorer and select 'Run Template', I get a list of errors that core System.* libs are missing, e.g.

```
  Generate.tt(21, 25): [CS0012] The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Is this a bug in Rider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to implementation details, Rider compiles T4 files targeting a version of .NET Framework, that's why it has problems with files referencing `net5.0` assemblies. As far as I understand what I see in `Mono.TextTemplating`, they target the runtime they are launched in instead. To solve your problem I'd suggest trying `Mono.TextTemplating` as a command-line tool - it might be able to compile files with `net5.0` references. To integrate that external tool into Rider, you can go to `File > Settings > Tools > Custom Tools`, disable `Bundled T4 Template Executor` and add a custom tool for `Mono.TextTemplating` CLT.

To answer your question: yes, it probably can be called a bug

Comment: Thanks! Will continue the conversation in JetBrains' issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-60238

Comment: As of net6.0, running with the latest release of Rider, the issue is still at large. The instructions for disabling the T4 custom tool doesn't work. Clicking edit will display it as disabled, but the custom tool will continue working even after restarting the IDE. It turns out the tool is installed as part of the ForTea (4T) plugin and is bundled with Rider. If you disable the plugin, however, it will disable the T4 custom tool. Adding the custom tool doesn't work and you lose syntax coloring.